# Create different print composers from different layers added to QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm using QGIS 2.8.3 with windows 10. I want to know if it's possible and how  to create, using python code, from each layer (in the table of content) a print composer to each one of them.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: I developed one script to create different vector layers with a defined colours legend for 6 maps with the same extent that's working perfect.                                                                                               Now I want to define in a python code a print composer for each one of these layers using a defined basic template with same scalebar, north arrow, text boxes  and legend. how can I do this, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You might use this code if you want but you need to improve it.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtXml import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

layers =iface.legendInterface().layers()
canvas=iface.mapCanvas()

for layer in layers:
    myFile = "your qpt path"
    myTemplateFile = file(myFile, 'rt')
    myTemplateContent = myTemplateFile.read()
    myTemplateFile.close()
    myDocument = QDomDocument()
    myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent, False)
    newcomp = iface.createNewComposer()
    newcomp.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)
    newcomp.composition().refreshItems()
    for a in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(a, False)
    iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True)
    newcomp.composition().refreshItems()
    map_item = newcomp.composition().getComposerItemById('map')
    map_item.setMapCanvas(canvas)
    map_item.zoomToExtent(canvas.extent())
    newcomp.composition().refreshItems()
    legend_item = newcomp.composition().getComposerItemById('legend')
    legend_item.updateLegend()
    newcomp.composition().refreshItems()
    imagePath ="your_path"+layer.name()+'.png'
    image = newcomp.composition().printPageAsRaster(0)
    image.save(imagePath,'png')
```

I have 4 layers in the Toc.

[image]

My basic template.qpt only have a legend ,map and tittle objects with Map ID="map" and Legend ID="legend".

Then this code generates 4 composition and 4 images,each one for each layer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank's Francisco. This code really loads the basic template previously created but don't repalce the different layers added automatically to QGIS's table of contents. The idea is to create for each print composer the basic template with each layer in map canvas (each layer to each print composer). Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Yo can try for each layer desactivate(visibility) other layers,after refresh composer and print.,or create list with composer path and depend the layer name choose a any composer.

Comment: Thank's Francisco, I search some exemples how to turn visible or not and I saw this exemple:                      iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(lyr, False) #  to desactivate visibility
iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(lyr, True) # to activate visibility                                                                                                     How can I use this exemple aplying individualy to different layers in map canvas and create one print composer for each layer? Can you help me? Thank's.

Comment: I edited my firt answer.